# Definition of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I have been trying to learn some Galois Theory from Weintraub's book of the same name. Weintraub uses the word “root” of a polynomial without ever defining exactly what it is.

I understand that a root of $f\in k[X]$ is some element $\alpha$ st $f(\alpha)=0$. But my problem is, to which field/ring/set is $\alpha$ the element of?

I think it should be defined as “Let $f\in k[X]$. A root of $f$ is any $\alpha$ in any field extension $L$ of $k$ st $f(\alpha)=0$.“

Is this right? If it is, is it also correct to define the root of $f\in A[X_1,....,X_n]$, $A$ any ring, as  any $\alpha:=(\alpha_1,....,\alpha_n)$ in any ring extension of $A$ st $f(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: That is pretty much correct. As stated, there is a problem that if you had two different extensions, roots in one could be considered as distinct from roots in the other. So the answer to the question "how many roots does the polynomial have" would be "a collection too large to be a set". So some understanding is needed that when talking about the roots of $f$, we need to refer to some specific context, not every context imaginable. But these are technical details. Usually when on speaks of roots, the context is understood.

Comment: Thanks very much. It would be really helpful if I can see this context a bit more explicitly. Also if there is a source where I can read about this, that would be great too :))

Comment: How does the theorem that “a polynomial over a field in one variable has at most $\deg(f)$ roots” fit into all this?

Comment: It is obviously referring to roots within the field itself. If it were referring to roots in some extension field, there would be no "at most". And if it were referring to roots in some extending ring, there would be no upper limit (for example, polynomials on the quarternions have uncountably many roots).

Comment: I will take a look at that statement and proof more carefully and get back to you. Btw it is Lemma 2.2.1 in Weintraub's Galois Theory.

Comment: If a polynomial over a field has a root $r$ in the field, then you can divide out $x - r$, giving a quotient of one lower degree. This only possible to continue until the degree is $0$, so the polynomial can have at most $n=\text{deg}(f)$ roots. If we consider roots in extension fields, the splitting field of the polynomial allows it to be written as a product of linear factors, so there it will have exactly $n$ roots, counting multiplicity. But for non-commutative extension rings, unique factorization does not hold, so there it can have even more roots.